# Trying to weight columns in ColumnTransformer using FunctionTransformer, Value Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transformer-model

I am trying to apply weights to ColumnTransformer for further classification (weights among columns). Given that it is not possible to do so direcly in the ColumnTransformer class (to my knowledge), I tried duplicating the values using numpy.

```
from numpy import repeat,ones
...
trf_list = [
  (
    feature,
    Pipeline([
      ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode', lowercase=True, stop_words='english', vocabulary=self.voc[feature])),
      ('weighter', FunctionTransformer(lambda row: repeat(row, weight)))
    ]),
    feature
  ) for feature, weight in zip(features, weights)]
trf = ColumnTransformer(transformers = trf_list, **kwargs)

test_data = np.array([[1, 9, 4], [2, 7, 1]])

expected_results = np.array([[1, 1, 9, 9, 4, 4], [2, 2, 7, 7, 1, 1]]) # with weight=2
```

Unfortunately, the output data is not flat, triggering a ValueError:

```
ValueError: The output of the 'description' transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 m.fit(x_train)

/home/cdsw/src/V3/model.py in fit(self, train_set)
     65   
     66   def fit(self, train_set):
---> 67     self.pipeline.fit(train_set)
     68     
     69     

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    339         """
    340         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 341         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    342         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    343                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    305                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    306                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 307                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    308             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    309             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    752     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    753         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 754             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    755         else:
    756             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    525 
    526         self._update_fitted_transformers(transformers)
--> 527         self._validate_output(Xs)
    528 
    529         return self._hstack(list(Xs))

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _validate_output(self, result)
    414                 raise ValueError(
    415                     "The output of the '{0}' transformer should be 2D (scipy "
--> 416                     "matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).".format(name))
    417 
    418     def _log_message(self, name, idx, total):

ValueError: The output of the 'description' transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).
```

( The input to the ColumnTransformer is a pandas dataframe if that helps)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your `FunctionTransformer` seems wonky.  Maybe rewrite the question with a minimal example (including a toy dataset) showing what you want as output vs. what you get from your `FunctionTransformer`?  You can add a separate question for the column transformer if you have further issues with that, but it seems to be superfluous to the actual problem you're facing right now.

Comment: Thank you, I edited and brought more details to the issue.